# Replacing a fractional quantity by one in inequalities

Tags: limits, inequality, logic

I was looking through proofs for the product law for limits and I stumbled upon a very clear one and managed to follow all the steps involving algebra and limits, but, near the end, in the proof, a fractional quantity is replaced by one when it is clearly stated that the fractional quality is less than one and greater or equal to zero, meaning you cannot treat it as one. However, in the step, it is mentioned that doing this does not harm the inequality and I just happen not to see the logic behind this as it is stated that the fractional quality is less than one. This step can be seen by this picture: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and second term go like this
$$
\frac{\lvert L \rvert \epsilon}{3(1+\lvert L \rvert)} =
\frac{\epsilon}{3} 
\underbrace{\frac{\lvert L \rvert}{1+\lvert L \rvert}}_{< 1}
<
\frac{\epsilon}{3}
$$
the third is clear, I hope.

This gives
$$
\lvert f(x) g(x) - LM \rvert <
\underbrace{\frac{\lvert L \rvert \epsilon}{3(1+\lvert L \rvert)}}_{<\epsilon/3} +
\underbrace{\frac{\lvert M \rvert \epsilon}{3(1+\lvert M \rvert)}}_{<\epsilon/3} +
\underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{3}}}_{=\epsilon/3}
< \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon
$$

Comment: Yes, I am comfortable with the third it is just the two. But, here you have mentioned that the quantity is less than epsilon over three, while in the proof it is treated as epsilon over three. I don't see this logic.

Comment: Oops, sorry I see my incredible idiocy. I was treating the "less than" sign as an equality.

Comment: I added the chain of inequalities.